# Scala: How to return a Some or Option

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have the following piece of code that I am trying to enhance:
I am using the `java.nio.file` package to represent a directory or a file as a `Path`.
So here goes:

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths,DirectoryStream,Files,
                      Path,DirectoryIteratorException}

val path: Path = Paths.get(directoryPath) 
var directoryStream: Option[DirectoryStream[Path]] = None

// so far so good

try {
    directoryStream = Some(Files.newDirectoryStream(pathO))

    // this is where i get into trouble
    def getMeDirStream: DirectoryStream[Path] =
        if (!directoryStream.isEmpty && directoryStream.isDefined)
            getMeDirStream.get
        else
            None

    // invoke the iterator() method of dstream here
}
```

The above piece of code will not compile because I do not know what to return in the else, and right now, for the life of me, I can only come up with `None`, which the compiler simply does not like and I would like to learn what should be its replacement. 
I want this example to be a learning lesson of `Option` and `Some` for me.

---

Okay, this is where I choke. I would like to check if the `directoryStream` is not empty and is defined, and then if this is the case, I would like to invoke `getMeDirStream.get` to invoke the `iterator()` method on it. 
The API for `Option` tells me that invoking the `get()` method could result in a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` if the option is empty.

If the directoryStream is empty I want to return something and not None, because IntelliJ is telling me that "Expression of type `None.type` doesn't conform to expected type `DirectoryStream[Path]`".

Now, I am being all naive about this.

I would like to know the following:

1. What should I return in the `else` other than `None`?
2. Should I wrap the `getMeDirStream.get` in a try-catch with a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, even though I am checking if the `directoryStream` is empty or not.?
3. What is the purpose of a try-catch in the `getMeDirStream.get`, if there is indeed such a need?
4. How can I clean up the above piece of code to incorporate correct checks for being `isDefined` and for catching appropriate exceptions?

Once I know what to return in the else (and after putting in the appropriate try-catch block if necessary), I would like to invoke the `iterator()` method on `getMeDirStream` to do some downstream operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific questions are difficult to address because it's unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve. In particular, when you ask what the purpose of the `try` block is... Well, you wrote it, so only you can answer that.

In general, you *never* call `get` on an `Option`. You either use pattern matching:

```
option match {
    case Some(value) => /* ... */
    case None =>        /* ... */
}
```

or you use methods like `map`, `flatMap`, and `foreach` (or the equivalent comprehension syntax that gpampara's code uses).

---

My revision of gpampara's answer:

```
import scala.collection.convert.wrapAll._
import scala.util.Try
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files, Path}

val getMeDirStream: Option[Iterator[Path]] =
  for {
    path <- Try(Paths.get("")).toOption
    directoryStream <- Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(path)).toOption
  } yield directoryStream.iterator
```

Changes:

- Using `Try(...).toOption` instead of `Either`
- Using implicits in `scala.collection.convert` to return the result as a Scala `Iterator`.

`Try` is similar to `Option`. Instead of `Some` and `None`, it has `Success` and `Failure` subtypes, and the failure case includes a `Throwable`, whereas `None` is just a singleton with no additional information.

Comment: I pondered about the try-catch, only because I looked at the API for Option.get and see that it throws an exception. After some subsequent research after I posted this question, I am seeing that your answers make sense. Very good answer

Comment: Both @gpampara and you provided correct answers. Since you revised his answer, I am going to marks yours the correct preferred answer. Thanks

Comment: Be wary of `Try` as  its behavior is not correct. It's not a valid monad (violates the left identify law). `Try` is not similar to `Option`, but instead is actually closer to `Either[Throwable, A]`, but with the stated violation.

Comment: The usage of the for-comprehension (`flatMap` and `map`) implies monad. The fact that scala doesn't clearly demonstrate this fact is a debate on its own.

Answer (score 2):

`Some` and `None` are subtypes of `Option`, but to be more correct, they are actually two different cases of `Option` or data constructors. In other words, even though Scala allows you to directly invoke a `Some` or a `None` you should still regard their type to be `Option`. The more important thing to take from this is that you should never under any circumstance invoke `Option#get` as it is unsafe.

The intention of `Option` is to indicate the possibility that a value does not exist. If you care about the errors, then you should probably look at using `Either` instead (or Scalaz's `Either` called `\/`).

You can keep the computation within the `Option` context and then only extract the value later, or provide a default.

```
def fromTryCatch[A](a: => A): Either[Throwable, A] = try { Right(a) } catch { case e: Throwable => Left(e) }

val getMeDirStream: Option[java.util.Iterator[Path]] =
  for {
    path <- fromTryCatch(Paths.get(directoryPath)).toOption
    directoryStream <- fromTryCatch(Files.newDirectoryStream(pathO)).toOption
  } yield directoryStream.iterator()
```

Later, or right after, you can get the iterator, or provide a default value:

```
val iterator = getMeDirStream.getOrElse(java.util.Collections.emptyIterator[Path])
```

Comment: Great points. I am upvoting your answer. It got me thinking on the right track.